# Strategy for scrolling a small area of content in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating an adventure game in Swift and allow the player to view their inventory. I have a very small set of items you can acquire (only about 25 items for your inventory) and I'd like them to display about 5-6 at a time in a rectangle. My thought was the player can scroll through them by swiping horizontally, and it will take them through the whole list, only ever showing 5-6 at a time across. The entire area is roughly 1/4 of the size of the screen.

I was looking at something like this https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift-SpriteKit-UIScrollView-Helper but when I tried it, it seems to be suited to a giant area (the entire screen) and the items then scroll off the screen when you scroll. I played with the content size thinking of it as a "viewport" but didn't have ay luck.

In my case, I want the items to scroll only within the confines of a 
300 x 150 rectangle or so. (so the item does not go beyond the width of the box containing it).

I couldn't really figure out a reliable way of doing this and wanted to ask someone if they've done something similar and how they achieved it. What's a good strategy for this? Perhaps a camera + pan using SKCameraNode?

Thanks so much!

Comment: @crashoverride777 perhaps you could let me know if I missed something regarding your helper class? Is there a way to do something in line with what I mentioned? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I can do it using a cropping mask - an initial test worked. Let me post something once I can figure it out but wanted to let anyone know in case they were wondering.